# Select multiple COUNTs for every day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table of Visitors.
Visitor has the following columns:

**Id**

**StartTime** (Date)

**Purchased** (bool)

**Shipped** (bool)

For each day within the last 7 days, I want to select 3 counts of the Visitors who have that day as **StartTime**:

- The count of total visitors
- The count of total visitors where **Purchased** = true
- The count of total visitors where **Shipped** = true

Ideally the returned result would be:

```
Day    Total    TotalPurchased    TotalShipped
1      100      67                42
2      82       61                27
etc...
```

I am used to .NET Linq so this has proved to be quite a challenge for me.

All I have come up with so far is the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM [dbo].[Visitors]
WHERE DAY([StartTime]) = DAY(GETDATE())
```

It selects the total of the current day just fine, however I feel pretty stuck right now so it'd be nice if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do `GROUP BY DAY([StartTime])`

Comment: I guess this is for SQL server? could you tag the DBMS accordingly please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last 7 days use the query proposed by Stanislav but with this `WHERE` clause

```
   SELECT DAY([StartTime]) theDay,
           COUNT(*) AS Tot,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Purchased=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotPurch,    
           SUM(CASE WHEN Shipped=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotShip
    FROM [dbo].[Visitors]
    WHERE [StartTime] BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GETDATE()
    GROUP BY DAY([StartTime])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Purchased=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalPurchased,    
       SUM(CASE WHEN Shipped=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalShipped
FROM [dbo].[Visitors]
WHERE DAY([StartTime]) = DAY(GETDATE())
```

and add GROUP BY DAY([StartTime]) as jarlh mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple select that will give you the dataset you want

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,StartTime, getdate())+1 as [Day], -- Add 1 to display 1 to 7 instead of 0 to 6
COUNT(*) as Total, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Purchased = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalPurchased, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Shipped = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalShipped 
FROM Visitors
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,startTime,GETDATE()) < 6
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,startTime,GETDATE())
ORDER BY 1
```

This query will not take into consideration the time component of the date.